# Getting substrings from <br />

Tags: c#, line-breaks, substr

I have a string full of ID's from a database

When I called the database to retrieve the data, I stored all the data in one string with a `<br />` in between all the ID's.

```
 cmd = new OleDbCommand(getCode, conn);
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    custCodes += rdr[0].ToString() + "<br />";
                }
```

now I want to run the ID's from the string one by one to retrieve the rest of the data from the database.

I want to use a substring to check the ID's one by one.
So far I have something like this:

```
String str=custCodes ;
        int index = 0;


        while (index != first.Length)
        {
            int indexOf = first.IndexOf("<br />");
             str = first.Substring(indexOf);
            index += 1;
        }
```

but I'm getting confused as to how I'm supposed to carry on.
Must I use an array, and store the codes in the array and then run it through the database?
I know my code is wrong, but I'm stumped as to how to fix it.
Substrings have never been my fav part of coding.

Comment: Why do you store the id's with `<br />` at all? You should do that at the very last place when you want to show them. You should even use a webdatabound control  instead like a repeater if you're using ASP.NET.

Comment: Sorry. was going to use a comma instead. but it should still be fine right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] ids = yourIds.Split(new string[] { "<br />" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

And with the ids array, you can use a StringBuilder to form a big sql string to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you store the id's with '
'?. To filter result one by one and show them? then please store the results in a datatable or an arraylist. then you can filter the result using index or column name. like

better is to store all the columns OR the columns you want to a datatable, like if you want

column names "id","name","email"

```
DataTable getdt(){
MySqlConnection conn = null;
            MySqlDataAdapter da ;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            String sql="select id,name,email from tablename ";
            conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            da=new MySqlDataAdapter(sql,conn);



            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                DataSet dsl = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(dsl,"Table");
                dt = dsl.Tables["Table"];
                return dt;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                String err = ex.Message;
                return dt;
            }
              }
```

and in the front end

just do the following code to split it

```
DataTable ddt=new DataTable();
ddt=getdt();

int le=ddt.Rows.Count;

for(int i=0; i<le; i++){

int id=ddt.Rows[i]["id"];
String name=ddt.Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
}
```

you can also use ArrayList.

dont need to find id of results and then run dbcall for each ids to extract other columns. this will slow down your application. please use sql adapter instead of mysql adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String.Split method, to get array of IDs from your string

Here is the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx

```
var ids = custCodes.Split("<br />");
foreach(var item in ids)
{
   //Check the current id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a really strange way of doing things but you could use the following: -

```
string[] custIds = custCodes.Split("<br />");

foreach(string s in custIds)
{
   int id = Convert.ToInt32(s);
   //Get record from DB with id etc..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split the string into an array using an array of "split-chars" - in your case, just `<br />`:

```
var ids = idList.Split(new string[]{"<br />"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

That should give you an array of type string, which you can parse to `int`'s, or whatever you may need.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a example in Java. If you have all id's saved in CustCodes, you can do it in this way:

```
String[] ids = CustCodes.split("<br />");

for(int i = 0; i < ids.lenght; i++)    

system.out.println(ids[i])
```

I hope this can help you.
You should find the same function (split) in c#

If you need more help, just tell me. :)